# How to add timestamp certificate without signature using setasign

Tags: pdf, timestamping

I want to add timestamp certificate using setasign. I have tried to do it using `timestamp()` method. But after adding it, when I am checking it, it's showing as signed certificate instead of Timestamp certificate. I have also tried `createTimestampSignature()` method & result is same. Is there any way to add timestamp certificate without any signing certificate?

Comment: I am not sure you can found an answer about setasign in SO bc setasign commercial and it has not an dedicated tag :/. Maybe you should send an email to setasign support.

Comment: I have not found any solution for it. Thanks for your suggestion, I will do it.